# How to Display thai calendar in MonthCalendar control regardless of current culture

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, calendar, globalization

I am working on c# winforms.
I have taken MonthPicker control on windows form.
I want to dispaly Thai Calendar regardless what culture is set on user's desktop machine as shown in below figure.

[image]

When user's machine culture is set to **english** it shows **english calendar**.
when user's machine culture is set to **thai** it shows **thai calendar**. I want **thai calendar in both the case**.

I have tried with below line of code before **InitializeComponent()** but not getting desired output.
Is there any mistak that I am doing or Is there any other way to achive the same?

```
system.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("th-TH");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("th-TH");
```

Comment: What version of the .NET framework & what version of Visual Studio (I presume) are you using?

Comment: .NET Framework 3.5 and visual studio 2008

Comment: An [MS Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889834) I found describes the issue you seem to be having even though the article is written with respect to VS 2005 and .NET 2.0.

Comment: it looks like issue is still persist in VS2008 and .NET 3.5. Don't you think so?

Comment: That's what I suspect too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is mentioned in an [MS Support article regarding VS 2005 and .NET 2.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889834), you may be dealing with the same issue it describes:

> This behavior occurs because the DateTimePicker control and the MonthCalendar control are Microsoft Windows common controls. Therefore, the operating system's user locale determines the user interface of these controls.

One way to check for this of course is to change your OS's user locale & see whether your `MonthCalendar` follows the change.

I do not know of a way to work around the `MonthCalendar` control's deference to the OS's user locale, but one possibility you might consider is an alternative, locale-aware calendar control.

For example, a [locale-aware calendar control described on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45684/Culture-Aware-Month-Calendar-and-Datepicker) sounds hopeful.  3rd-party (e.g. Telerik, Infragistics etcetera) calendar controls might also yield something.